# three column dynamic css layout with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, layout, dynamic

I am trying to achieve dynamic three-column layout with a sticky footer with CSS.

I have uploaded a semi-working static solution to codepen to ilustrate what i am after( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojYWzO ).

I suppose the problem lies somewhere with my wrapper container...

```
.main{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -4em;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The footer should always be stuck to the bottom - the user shouldnt need to scroll to see the footer.

The three colums should automatically adjust their height and fill the space to the footer regardless of the content.

The circle in the middle column should take up as much space as possible for witch I want to use mediaqueries.

I am not able to force the three columns to be of equal height / auto strech to the extend of the availabe height.

How do I solve this?